# Android - can't store a list in the Application class instance

Tags: java, android, arraylist, global-variables

I'm trying to store a list in the `Application` class instance as a global variable in one of my `Android` applications. Below is my `Application` class code:

```
public class DefectsApplication extends Application{

private NormalUser normalUser;

private ArrayList<Complaint> complaintList;

public String getTestString() {
    return testString;
}

public void setTestString(String testString) {
    this.testString = testString;
}

private String testString;

public NormalUser getNormalUser() {
    return normalUser;
}

public void setNormalUser(NormalUser normalUser) {

    this.normalUser = normalUser;
}

public ArrayList<Complaint> getComplaintList() {
    return complaintList;
}

public void setComplaintList(ArrayList<Complaint> m_complaints) {
    this.complaintList = complaintList;
}
}
```

Below is my code which is trying to access the fields from the `Application` class instance:

```
DefectsApplication defectsApplication = ((DefectsApplication)getApplicationContext());
defectsApplication.setComplaintList(m_complaints);
defectsApplication.setTestString("urghhhhhhhhh");
ArrayList<Complaint> complaintList = defectsApplication.getComplaintList();
String s = defectsApplication.getTestString();
```

In the above code, `m_complaints` is a list of objects. When I try to store a `String`, it works. But for a list, it doesn't. Please, help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: "I'm trying to store a list in the Application class as a global variable" -- why do you think that this is a good idea? "But for a list, it doesn't" -- please explain what "it doesn't" means. What are your symptoms? Are you crashing? Are you getting a compile error?

Comment: Yes. I would've explained it more. The complaintList was always coming as null when I tried to get it from the Application class. Actually Onik has come up with the answer. It's just a typo in the setter method of the list in the Application class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, a typo is taking place:

```
public void setComplaintList(ArrayList<Complaint> m_complaints) {
    this.complaintList = complaintList;
}
```

You're setting `this.complaintList` to itself which is initially `null`. Try

```
public void setComplaintList(ArrayList<Complaint> m_complaints) {
    this.complaintList = m_complaints;
}
```